# Adding a Records Count row to top of query results in SQL

Tags: sql

I want a row count above my query results. I found an article that suggested using sections but the summary and select query do not have matching columns/data types. 
Ex.
Total Records 25

```
Col1   Col2  Col3...
XXXX   XXXX  XXXX
```

example from the suggestion I found but my columns and datatypes do not match between the two queries

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT [Section]=2, Col1, Col2, ..., Value1, Value2
FROM #TEMP
UNION ALL
SELECT [Section]=1, 'Total', '----', ..., SUM(Value1), SUM(Value2)
FROM #TEMP
) AS T
ORDER BY [Section], Col1, ...
```

Comment: You'll have to monkey with that second query (the second half of the union) to make the column types match (quantity and type). I would suggest just NOT doing this though as it's a very strange requirement.

Comment: Someone suggested I look into group by rollup

Comment: I have to agree with @JNevill that this is a particularly odd requirement. Any reason why this type of summation can't be handled in the application layer?

Answer (score 0):

To be polite, you are not using the tool the way it is meant to be used.  The contents of those columns are strongly typed.  Each one contains strings, dates, numbers, etc, and you're adding another row with strings on top.

The only way I can see this working is if you were to convert all of your columns to VARCHAR columns and cast all of your data to VARCHAR(MAX) in the query.

Otherwise, I think that the most reasonable solution would be to perform a second query for the totals.

Comment: I see your point.  My issue is that I need to produce a text file and they want a row at the top of the text file that says Total Data Record Count = X.  I have not done this before and am trying to understand how I would do that.